# Spark- Spark's Catalyst optimizer is trying to reference the column before it's being dropped

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I did that

```
val columnsToDrop = Seq("header")
val dfWithoutHeader: Dataset[Row] = if (columnsToDrop.forall(dataset.columns.contains)) {
  dataset.drop(columnsToDrop: _*)
} else {
  dataset
}
```

I tried to drop column from schema in spark scala and then I got this **error after that I got error: Column 'header' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following ?**
Could you help me please ?

I would like to delete column name from schema in spark scala

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? Are you sure the error comes from this piece of code?